# Chrome extension on a React page

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, google-chrome-extension, react-redux

I have a simple chrome extension that auto-fills the form on a page with default values.

manifest.json file

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Form Filler",
  "description": "This extension auto fills form in a specific page.",
  "version": "1.0",
  "icons": {
    "128": "128x128.png"

  },

  "page_action": {
    "default_icon": "19x19.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_title": "Form Filler"
  },
  "options_page":"options.html",

  "background": {
    "scripts": ["eventPage.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },


  "content_scripts":[
    {
      "matches": ["http://test-site.com/*"],
      "js": ["content.js", "jquery-3.1.0.min.js"]

    }
  ],

  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "storage",
    "http://test-site.com/*"
        ]
}
```

and this is content.js file

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse){
    if (request.act == "fill"){     
        let name =  request.name;  
        let email =  request.email;                      
        $('#name').val(name);
        $('#email').val(email);
    }
});
```

That works perfectly fine on a normal HTML page.

But it doesn't work on a react page.

I guess obvious reason is that things are handled by state and if I can somehow alter the state, I should be able to get it working.

I tried this code ( file = content.js )but no success

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender) {
    if (request.act == "fill") {
        this.setState({"form.name": "My Name"});
    }
}.bind(this));
```

This is the eventPage.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse){
    if (request.todo == "showPageAction")
    {
        chrome.tabs.query({active:true,currentWindow: true}, function(tabs){
            chrome.pageAction.show(tabs[0].id);
        });
    }
});
```

I am unable to access the state in the extension JS.

What would be the proper way to perform this task?

Comment: You can try focusing the element and using document.execCommand with 'insertText' parameter. Or try sending a 'change' and an 'input' event (not via jQuery) on the element.

Comment: Can you share a little bit more code, e.g. where you adding this event listener, also can you check what `this` is when listener function is called.

Comment: @Grissom thanks, added full code. also wOxxOm thanks, looking into it

Comment: @Waku-2, can you share the code of component, where are you adding this listener, I guess it should be in componentDidMount method

Comment: Are you trying to use `React` in all `.js` files? OR just in specific files? I made a Chrome Extension with React, but I only used React on the `Options` page (similar to the `Popup` page) since I wanted to display a form to the user, and in the `content scripts` I just used vanilla JavaScript to read / insert data from the page.